# Laravel - Get data based on date range using eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Heei, I want to show data according to daterange. Specifically data on this day and 6 days to go. Here's my code now.

**Controller**

```
$hari = [];

for ($i=0; $i < 6; $i++) 
{
   $hari[] = date("Y M d") + $i;
}

$booking_room = jadwal_meeting::whereBetween('tanggal', [$hari, $hari + 6])->get();
return view('homepage')->with($booking_room);
```

***Note***: 'tanggal' is a field on table.

But I just get error like this

> Unsupported operand types
>   : `$booking_room = jadwal_meeting::whereBetween('tanggal', [$hari, $hari + 6])->get();`

What's wrong with my code, anyone can help me please :)

Comment: Is `$hari` a string or a `Carbon` instance?

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir the result of `$hari` should be a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$hari` is an array, you have to use something like this:

```
$booking_room = jadwal_meeting::whereBetween('tanggal', [$hari[0], $hari[5]])->get();
```

Or more general:

```
$booking_room = jadwal_meeting::whereBetween('tanggal', [$hari[0], end($hari)])->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, you save my time :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it will help you.

```
$from = '2018-04-12'; 
$to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($from. ' + 6 days'));

$reservations = Reservation::whereBetween('tanggal', [$from, $to])
->get();
```

Thanks,